# Using Regex to match words in a list,

Tags: python, regex, list

I am very new to regex and am trying to find all words that begin with each letter of a word within a list.

For example I have the list:

```
[' MRI', 'fMRI ', 'PPE', 'FFE']
```

I am trying to find words within the text using the letters in the words that would match these and if not then ignore it.

So for the list above find if the text contains

```
Magnetic resonance imaging
functional Magnetic resonance imaging
personal protection equipment
None
```

I have found several ways that do this but not when the words are in a list.

Is anyone able to help here, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output for this testcase? Does the third line for example match with `PPE` as the case is not correct?

Comment: my expected output is a list with the not abbreviated words in. I see what you mean and was hoping the search would be non case senesitive

Answer (score 1):

Use the `re` library. Use `flags=re.I` option therein when case-insensitive.

```
import re
acronyms=['  MRI', 'fMRI', 'PPE', 'FFE']
text="""pull porous experiment
 public protection expertise
personal protective 
equipment
here is a magnetic resonance interglobular section
with a certain energy measure is on a table"""
matched={}
for a in acronyms:
  pattern=''
  for letter in a.strip():
    pattern+='[ ]*{}[^ \n]+[ \n]+'.format(letter)
  pattern+=''
  print(a.strip(),pattern)
  matched.update({a.strip():re.findall(pattern,text,flags=re.I)})

print(matched)
```

matched should now contain a dictionary with each acronym and a list of matches per each.

The output `matched` is now (notice the acronyms have been stripped of leading and trailing spaces)

```
{'MRI': [' magnetic resonance interglobular '], 'fMRI': [], 'PPE': ['pull porous experiment\n ', 'public protection expertise\n', 'personal protective \nequipment\n'], 'FFE': []}
```

This allows results to span multiple lines, but those end of line characters (`\n`) are included in the match results. If you prefer those to be spaces, you could use, for example, the `re.sub` to replace `[\n ]+` with .

Here is a reference on the `re` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. Here's one of many potentially useful generic explanations of regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto.

Comment: This looks on the right lines although I receieve this error: re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 22

Comment: Would you mind explaining the repattern so I could learn what it means. Thanks

Comment: you need to insert tab before `pattern += ' )'`

Comment: I tried this code and it doesn't work... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Strangely this does not return anything. Would it affect the re is some of the text has dashs such as 'BOLD' being 'blood-oxygen-level dependent'

Comment: Also some may contain a half acroynm such as functional MRI

Comment: The `[^ ]+` requires one or more non-space characters. See modification though.

Comment: Some are now appearing, although it is picking up some acronyms in the text which are not correct. e.g I have an example 'EEG' which is not referred to in the text and the dictionary value has come out as 'energy'.

Comment: I believe a solution to this is having the words found consecutively, which is what I have been trying to unsuccessfully complete

Comment: Another example is that MRI has matched with 'measure is'

Comment: The 'EEG' leading to picking up "energy" and "MRI" matching 'measure is' is the problem I was trying to correct having to do with requiring a space between words, but still being able to pick up words that begin at the beginning of a line, and not needing a space at the end of a line. This is easily fixed. Will provide edited code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212114/discussion-between-jpf-and-geds133).

Comment: @geds133 The additional request in comments for "functional MRI" makes the problem much more complicated, because a general solution would include all binary combinations of, per acronym letter, regular expressions to capture words, and the letter itself. i.e. a three letter acronym would have 2^3 = 8 regex search patterns, four letter acronym would have 2^4 = 16 search patterns. Could be done but with a more extensive list of acronyms could lead to lots of false positives.